# Why was the unique method of shared pointer removed in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, smart-pointers

In C++20 `shared_ptr<T>::unique()` [was removed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/unique) (not deprecated ... completely removed). Apart from the fact that I have to hunt those calls in a codebase and remove them, I'm annoyed with the following quote:

> This function was deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20 because use_count is only an approximation in multithreaded environment (see Notes in use_count).

- What does the above excerpt mean?
- What can I replace it with? How am I supposed to remove it?
- If that's such a disadvantage how was the method included in the first place?

Comment: 1 - It means what it says, that the result can be inaccurate when multiple threads are involved. Presumably it's a `memory_order_relaxed` read of the reference counter. 2 - Assuming a single thread, `.use_count() == 1` would work. But I'm curious what do you need it for.  3 - Somebody made a bad judgement, not the first time it happens.

Comment: IMO the referenced [Notes in std::shared_ptr<T>::use_count](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count#Notes) on that page are very well describing the reason. No need to repeat it here.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't need it, it already exists and a ticket to remove it from our codebase fell on my desk.

Comment: If you interpret the ticket literally, you can just replace it with `.use_count() == 1` everywhere. But you should consult the ticket author to see whether the intent was to fix the bad code that needs this in the first place.

Comment: As long as your codebase doesn't use the old `.unique()` or new `.use_count() == 1` a multi-threaded fashion, you're golden.  But if it did use `.unique()` in a multi-threaded fashion, the code is already broken and will need a different multi-threaded coordination mechanism.  (A `.use_count() == 1` being true is no protection, because another thread's weak pointer can at any time acquire a strong pointer from that weak pointer.)